# Azure Mobile Services - UpdateAsync Does Not Update All Fields

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services and am running into an issue with the "UpdateAsync" method.  For many of the properties I am storing in my item the UpdateAsync method works just fine.  For others the update is completely ignored.  Has anyone ran into an issue like this before?  The call I am making is nothing fancy and the code is below.

It seems that the issue of the property not being updated may be limited to properties that contain a number in the name.  For example CP20M is one of my properties that is not updating through this method.  Another property, "Weight" updates without issue.  Both are doubles.  Does that make any sense?  The only way I have of updating these fields that seems to work is to delete the entry and insert a new entry.  That will get the appropriate values into all properties.

Any ideas are appreciated.

```
public async Task UpdateUserProfileItemAsync(UserProfile userProfile)
{
    await _userProfileTable.UpdateAsync(userProfile);
    await SyncAsync();
}
```

Comment: when you call a PATCH via the REST API what doe sthe object look like?  Is the CP20M field present?  It could be your JSON serializer settings are removing default values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm still learning the ropes of Azure Mobile Services, what is the best way to perform this test?

Comment: I like to use Postman (which is a chrome extension), to send REST API calls.  So you would do a PATCH to <service>/table/tablename/recordid, with a content type header of application/json and the body of your object.  (Like { "CP20M": 20.5, "Weight": 100.0 }) and see what is returned.  Also, by default you will need to specify the X-ZUMO-APPLICATION header with a value of your application key.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I did this test and did a patch to my object where I updated both the Weight and the CP20M.  The response was OK, with the body portion of the response containing my object with the CP20M at its old value and the Weight at its new value.  The database also only updated the Weight.  The CP20M remained its previous value.  Any idea what may cause that?

Comment: As an update, I've renamed my troublesome field from CP20M to CpTwentyM and it works just fine now.  I would still like to figure this out, but I do have a work-around now.

Comment: Having the same issue, working through it now as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the field you are having problem with. It worked for me.

Comment: This is a good working around.  Unfortunately I never discovered why this issue occurred.